# QR decomposition Fortran error

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, transformation, qr-decomposition, plato

I have a problem with QR decomposition method. I use dgeqrf subroutine for decomposition but there is no error in the compiler but it gives a problem after that. I haven't found where is the mistake.
Another question is, A=Q*R=> if A matrix has zero, Can decomposition be zero or lose the rank.

```
program decomposition

!CONTAINS
!subroutine Qrdecomposition(A_mat, R)
real,dimension(2,2)   :: A_mat    !real,dimension(2,2),intent(inout)   
:: A_mat
real,dimension(2,2)   :: R        !real,dimension(2,2),intent(out)     
:: R
real,dimension(2,2)                  :: A
integer                              :: M,N,LDA,LWORK,INFO
real,allocatable, dimension(:,:)     :: TAU
real,allocatable, dimension(:,:)     :: WORK
external   dgeqrf
M=2
N=2
LDA=2
LWORK=2
INFO=0
A_mat(1,1)=4
A_mat(1,2)=1
A_mat(2,1)=3
A_mat(2,2)=1
A=A_mat

call dgeqrf(M,N,A,TAU,WORK,LWORK,INFO)
R=A
print *,R,WORK,LWORK

!end subroutine Qrdecomposition
end program decomposition
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see three mistakes in your code:

1) You forgot the `LDA` argument to `dgeqrf`,

2) `TAU` and `WORK` must be explicitly allocated,

3) All arrays should be declared with double precision to be consistent with `dgeqrf` interface:

```
program decomposition

!CONTAINS
!subroutine Qrdecomposition(A_mat, R)
! Note: using '8' for the kind parameter is not the best style but I'm doing it here for brevity.
real(8),dimension(2,2)   :: A_mat    !real,dimension(2,2),intent(inout)
real(8),dimension(2,2)   :: R        !real,dimension(2,2),intent(out)
real(8),dimension(2,2)                  :: A
integer                              :: M,N,LDA,LWORK,INFO
real(8),allocatable, dimension(:,:)     :: TAU
real(8),allocatable, dimension(:,:)     :: WORK
external   dgeqrf
M=2
N=2
LDA=2
LWORK=2
INFO=0
A_mat(1,1)=4
A_mat(1,2)=1
A_mat(2,1)=3
A_mat(2,2)=1
A=A_mat

allocate(tau(M,N), work(M,N))
call dgeqrf(M,N,A,LDA,TAU,WORK,LWORK,INFO)
R=A
print *,R,WORK,LWORK

!end subroutine Qrdecomposition
end program decomposition
```

In certain situations, Fortran does perform automatic allocation of arrays, but it should generally not be counted on and it is not the case here.

**EDIT** Point 3 was pointed out by roygvib, see below.

Comment: Thanks for helping :) What did you find R(transformation matrix)?

Comment: This is what it showed on my machine: `262144.906  -3.0  -6.49038268E+32  0.624999940`.

Comment: Isn't the kind of input arrays (real) and the subroutine dgeqrf (double precision) inconsistent? http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.1.1/html/sgeqrf.f.html http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/dgeqrf.f.html

Comment: if A=[4 1;3 1],the result should be R=[ -5.00     -1.40 ;0.00     0.20]. But the code result=[-5 0.33;-1.4 0.2] something is wrong because A(2,1) should be zero for orthogonal transformation

Comment: Actually you are right, because I am using real but when I try sqeqrf, the result is so different

Comment: @Nobody I think the 0.33 in the R(2,1) element represents part of the "v" vectors (see the manual pages above). That is, the returned A matrix contains the values of R in the upper triangular part (including the diagonals), while the lower triangular part of A gives info about the Q matrix (in terms of the v vectors). The correct (2,1) element of the R should be 0 (probably).

Comment: Also please note that the 2-dim array "A" in Fortran is column-major, so if you print "A" (or "R") as "print *, A", then the values are printed in this order: A(1,1), A(2,1), A(1,2), A(2,2). [As for sgeqrf(), I got similar results when used with "real" arrays, so something seems strange...(note that types need to match with routines.)]

Comment: @roygvib Yes you are right R(2,1) represents the "v" vector, How can I obtain only R=[-5 -14.4;0 0.2] because I don't need the diagonal element for QR factorization or do I need to use other subroutine for Qr factorization?

Comment: @Nobody I think you can get R from the upper triangular part of the returned A matrix (by ignoring the lower triangular part), i.e., R(:,:) = 0 then R(i,j) = A(i,j) for all 1 <= i <= j <= N.

Comment: @roygvib You are right that it should be double precision. I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Thanks I changed it :)